# How to match repeating patterns (that have random text between them) using regex?

Tags: python, regex

Given the string below:

```py
"This is my value 3435 string with number ID123. Also I have the value 1234 with number ID999. Also a random number 23 preceding the real value 3434 and the number ID34"
```

I would like to get the values and the IDs that close to each other:

- 3435, ID123
- 1234, ID99
- 3434, ID34

How could I do it? I'm using python 3.7

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `value` is always numeric and space separated and `ID` is always formatted as "ID" followed by numeric digits:

```py
>>> import re
>>> s = "This is my value 3435 string with number ID123. Also I have the value 1234 with number ID999"
>>> re.findall(r'\s?(\d+)\s.*?(ID\d+)', s)
[('3435', 'ID123'), ('1234', 'ID999')]
```

If you can guarantee there are no numeric digits between `value` and `ID` you can use this:

```py
>>> import re
>>> s = "This is my value 3435 string with number ID123. Also I have the value 1234 with number ID999. Also a random number 23 preceding the real value 3434 and the number ID34"
>>> re.findall(r'\s?(\d+)\s[^\d]*?(ID\d+)', s)
[('3435', 'ID123'), ('1234', 'ID999'), ('3434', 'ID34')]
```

Comment: That looks fine, but I'm also need to deal with random numbers in the string. I've updated the question

Comment: Added another possibility depending on input format

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```py
import re

text = "This is my value 3435 string with number ID123. Also I have the value 1234 with number ID999. Also a random number 23 preceding the real value 3434 and the number ID34"

nums = re.findall('\d{4}', text)
ids = re.findall('ID\d+', text)

result = [(num, id) for num, id in zip(nums, ids)]
print(result) # [('3435', 'ID123'), ('1234', 'ID999'), ('3434', 'ID34')]
```

Or simply:

```py
result = re.findall('\d{4}|ID\d+', text)

print(result) # ['3435', 'ID123', '1234', 'ID999', '3434', 'ID34']
```

Comment: I've updated the question to a third case

Comment: @MatheusOliveira I updated the answer to account for that, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
x = "This is my value 3435 string with number ID123. Also I have the value 1234 with number ID999"
import re
id = re.findall(r'\bID\w+', x)
x = x.split(' ')
numbers = [char for char in x if char.isnumeric()]
res = {numbers[i]: id[i] for i in range(len(numbers))}
print(res)
```

Returns a dictionary